# Return response from stripe api from backend to the page

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, stripe-payments, velo

I am trying to return the response object i get from stripe after creating a subscription using npm.

```
import Stripe from 'stripe';

const key = require("stripe")("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

export function subscribe(cus, items) {

key.subscriptions.create({
  customer: cus,
  items: items
});
}
```

When I used fetch (POST) i used to do this:

```
 if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
    // transaction successful - get charge ID
    const ret = await response.json();
    let subId = ret.id
    return {"subId": subId};
}

  // transaction failed - return error messages and codes
    let res = await response.json();
    let err = res.error.message;
    let code = res.error.code;
    let type = res.error.type;
    return {"error": err, "code": code, "type": type};
}
```

But in node i don't understand. I need to return the entire response so that I can store the subscription id, customer id ,etc.

I tried using this but does not work even though the subscription is successful

```
key.subscriptions.create({
  customer: cus,
  items: items
}, function(err, subscription) {
    if (err) {
            let response = err;
            return{response};
        }
            let response = subscription;
            return{response};
        }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [example](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create?lang=node) from Stripe API Documentation 
inside Call back function you will get desired Output

```
var stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc");

app.post('/stripe/sub', (req, res) => {

  stripe.subscriptions.create({
  customer: "cus_EcmCu9HT7EZWEH",
  items: [
    {
      plan: "emerald-company-234",
    },
  ]
}, function(err, subscription) {
    if(subscription){
        res.send(subscription)
      }
  }
);

});
```

Comment: I know this example. But i can't get my head around what to code in the call back function so that the response will be returned to the page.

Comment: if you are using express then simply call res.send() to send the response back to the client. or if you want a response on HTML page then you can refer this  https://www.codementor.io/naeemshaikh27/node-with-express-and-ejs-du107lnk6